# How does jQuery's hierarchy work when it comes to the "this" selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, jquery-selectors, this

For example, if I were to use this code:

```
$(".Class").children(:last).click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(":not(:last)").toggle();
}
```

Would "this" refer to the ".Class" class, or would it refer to the last child of the specified ".Class" class?

Comment: 'this' refers to the last children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` would refer to the DOM element that results matched in the final selector in the chain that triggers the event; in this case, the [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) child of `.Class`. So, the event would trigger if you click the `last` child of the last `.Class` class. See in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tasrG/1/) how only `foo2` triggers the alert.

```
<div class="Class">
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
    <div> </div>
   <div> </div> <!--This is the last child of .Class-->

</div>
```

Except, it won't work as you've posted it, since `:last` should be in quotes as a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wouldn't have remembered that I needed quotes there.

Answer (score 2):

It would refer to the element clicked. That is, the last element in the element with a class of `Class` at the time the event listener was bound. If you added another element after the previous last element in the same parent after the event listener was already bound, it would still be listening to what was *previously* the last one, and `this` will also be the previous last one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yours was quite confusing though.

Comment: Hm? This doesn't sound correct. The `children()` function will filter it down to child elements of `.Class`, not the `.Class` itself.

Comment: @yahelc: You're right. I guess I didn't read carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is the last child in that case. It is always the last element matching before the click word.

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the current context you're operating in.  In the example you provided it would refer to the last child of the specified "Class" class.

If you were to do the following:

```
$(".Class").children().each(function(){
    ...
});
```

`$(this)` would refer to each child as it gets iterated over.